# Convert choice number to equal text in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have a table contains a field that hold one number that this number refrence to equal text value(e.g. 3: Male, 4:Female).

**My Question:**

How to convert this number to equal value with SQL script and without create any extra tables?

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: SELECT text from my_table WHERE Id = 3

Comment: Thanks POHH, CASE statement is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` as suggested by @POHH

```
 CASE WHEN numberfield = 3 THEN 'MALE'
      WHEN numberfield = 4 THEN 'FEMALE'
 END
```